# styled-components: style based on non-styled class parent

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Let's say I have this:

```
const Child = styled.button`
    background-color: grey;
`;

<div className="some-non-styled-class">
    <Child>Hello World</Child>
</div>;

<div className="some-other-non-styled-class">
    <Child>Hello World</Child>
</div>;
```

How can I style Child so it's "red" when under `some-non-styled-class` and "blue" when it's under `some-other-non-styled-class`?

I'm aware of the [ability to refer to other styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components), but I have a use case where I need to change styling based on an existing library with static class names.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this then:

```
export const Child = () => {
const [parentClass, setParentClass] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
  const currentClass = document.querySelector(".childComp").parentElement.className
  setParentClass(currentClass)
},[])

return (<MyStyledComponent className="childComp" parentClassName={parentClass}>
  {children}
  </MyStyledComponent>)
}
```

Comment: Nope because I don't have any details on the parent. To parent is from another library/team and it changes classnames independently from my component. It's a crap situation but it's what I have to work with.